# Restricting installing app from itunes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, itunes, mdm

How can I restrict a particular app from being installed via iTunes from device using Mobile Device Management or via other objectivec ways?

Comment: I don't think you can. Especially as iTunes is a 'legal' way of installing apps. What do you want to achieve? We might have an alternative solution for you?

Comment: I am working on a MDM (Mobile Device Management) solution and I want to restrict certain apps from getting installed via itunes app on device.

What would be the alternate solution you recommend?

Comment: So you are not even talking about limiting your own app? You want to prevent 3rd parties apps from being installed on the phones under your MDM control? Frankly I am not aware of any solution.

Answer (score 0):

MDM has a feature to prevent installation of ANY apps. However, it doesn't have a feature to target (prevent installation) of some specific apps.